# Which algorithm does Blender use for Inverse Kinematics?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Is there any documentation how the `Inverse Kinematics Bone Constraint` is implemented? I assume the problem is written in some kind of minimizing problem and `Iteratations` defines the number of steps for a minimizing algorithmn but I couldn't find any proof in the documentation.

Comment: You can see in the source code. [Here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/File_Structure) we see that IK stuff you are interested in is most likely in [/source/blender/ikplugin/](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/ikplugin/) It would make sense to provide context about why you are looking for this kind of information. Also keep in mind that proramming Blender is usually considered off-topic on Blender Stack Exchange (except Python). You will get better help on devtalk.blender.org forums on this topic.

Comment: Found some explainer in blender docs https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Animation/IK. Moreover, the code in source/blender/ikplugin might help as well.